# TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function in Google Chrome but working fine in Mozilla

Tags: modal-dialog

> Hello i use bootstrap 3.3.5 and jquery 1.11.3 and I import those file
>   in my homepage first jquery 1.11.3 and then bootstrap 3.3.5 but modal
>   is working fine on Mozilla but when running on google Chrome its
>   caught typeError.... dont understand whats problem

```
        <script src="ppthemeplugings/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="ppthemeplugings/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="ppthemeplugings/Custom/js/patientProgressNote.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**my html code**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="progressNoteFromModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Progress Note Form</h4>             
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="progressNoteModelBodyDiv"> </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-transparent pull-left"
                    type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button
                    class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-transparent pull-right"
                    type="button" onclick="setDataForTakeMedicine('takeMedicineItemNo','takeMedicineRxNo','takeMedicineDateTime','takeMedicineComments')">Take Medicine</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Modal call from java script**

```
function showProgressNoteFrom(){
    $('#progressNoteFromModal').modal('show');
    var ajaxURL = "showProgressNoteFromPatientProgressNote.do"
    $.ajax({
        async : false,
        url : ajaxURL,
        success : function(result) {
            $("#progressNoteModelBodyDiv").html(result);
        },
        complete:function (){
            $('#myTabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
            $('.summernote').summernote();
        }

    });



}
```

Comment: i am facing same problem. You find any solution?